# Word connect: pair up the words

Tags: wordplay, word-property

**Connect the words by pairs as appropriate.** Each word on the left connects to one word on the right, and vice versa.

[image]

CSV version (horizontal):

```
BOLA, COMPACT, CONSISTENT, GRAPH, MAGNETISM, METER, NORMAL, PHRASE, SITE
ALUMINUM, ARGUMENT, CONTRADICTION, GHOST, METRIC, PILCROW, QUADRATIC, REWORD, TICK
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The associations are due to

> the prefix [PARA-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/para-#English)

Thus

> PARA + BOLA ~ QUADRATIC
>  PARA + COMPACT ~ METRIC
>  PARA + CONSISTENT ~ CONTRADICTION
>  PARA + GRAPH ~ PILCROW
>  PARA + MAGNETISM ~ ALUMINIUM
>  PARA + METER ~ ARGUMENT
>  PARA + NORMAL ~ GHOST
>  PARA + PHRASE ~ REWORD
>  PARA + SITE ~ TICK

Comment: Wha- How so fast!?

Comment: Okay this has to be a record.

Comment: @DannyuNDos BOLA is a word that I only have one or two associations with. There's also quite a mathematical element, which is my home turf.